# How can I detect which <View> my finger is currently on?

Tags: javascript, react-native, gesture, gesture-recognition

I have a structure like this:

```
<View style={container}>
    <View style={first}></View>
    <View style={second}><View>
    <View style={third}</View>
</View>
```

The container pretty much fills the whole screen.

When the user touches the container and moves the finger around without lifting the finger, I would like to know which `View` the finger is currently placed at.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [TouchableWithoutFeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback) to wrap around your views, and then you can call the [`onPressIn`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpressin) function to detect touch event.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect the touched view unless and until you don't have any touch event on it.

To do that you can use [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/touchableopacity) (respond to the press and have visual feedback when touched.) or [TouchableWithoutFeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/touchablewithoutfeedback) (it won't show any visual feedback when touched)

Below is the sample example as required:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from 'react-native'

export default class SampleComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

    }

    _onPressView = (viewName) => {
        console.log("Tapped View ===> ", viewName)
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPressView("FirstView")}>
                    <View style={styles.first}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPressView("SecondView")}>
                    <View style={styles.second}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPressView("ThirdView")}>
                    <View style={styles.third}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```